# Смена алгоритма шифрования Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Коллеги, имеется таблица с пользователями, там используется `SHA256` для шифрования пароля.
Необходимо использовать этот пароль, для авторизации в laravel.

Для проверки авторизации в Laravel 8 используется `Auth::attempt($credentials)`.

Как реализовать авторизацию с фасадом Auth, если в БД пароль зашифрован в SHA256?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покурив три часа документацию всё-таки реализовал.
Для выполнения такого финта нужно

1. Само собой должна быть модель вашей таблицы с пользователями.
2. Далее нужно создать своего провайдера который имплементирует методы `UserProvider`

   ```
   class CustomUserProvider implements UserProvider
    {
        protected $model;
        public function __construct($model)
        {
            $this->model = $model;
        }
        public function retrieveById($identifier): GenericUser
        {
            // тут ещё предстоит работа
        }

        public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
        {
        }

        public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
        {
            if (! array_key_exists('name', $credentials)) {
                return null;
            }
            $query = $this->newModelQuery();
            foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
                if (Str::contains($key, 'pass')) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (is_array($value) || $value instanceof Arrayable) {
                    $query->whereIn($key, $value);
                } else {
                    $query->where($key, $value);
                }
            }
            $userArray = $query->first()->getAttributes();
            // GenericUser is a class from Laravel Auth System
            return new GenericUser($userArray);
        }

        public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials): bool
        {
            if (! array_key_exists('pass', $credentials)) {
                return false;
            }
            // Тут алгоритм проверки пароля.
            if ($user->getAuthPassword() == hash(64,$credentials['pass'],false)) return true;
            return false;
        }
        protected function newModelQuery($model = null)
        {
            return is_null($model)
                ? $this->createModel()->newQuery()
                : $model->newQuery();
        }

        /**
         * Create a new instance of the model.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
         */
        public function createModel(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
        {
            $class = '\\'.ltrim($this->model, '\\');

            return new $class;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Далее регистрируем его в `Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php`

   ```
   Auth::provider('customuserprovider', function ($app, array $config) {
        return new CustomUserProvider($config['model']);

    });
   ```
4. Далее добавляем его в конфигурации `config/auth.php`

   ```
   'providers' => [
       'users' => [
           'driver' => 'customuserprovider',
           'model' => App\Models\User::class,
           'table' => 'TABLE_NAME',
       ],
   ],
   ```

Comment: А разве нельзя было указать sha256 в конфиге (hashing)?